# div or modal full screen over md-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is posible to open a div in a fullscreen mode when the div is inside a md-tab control?
I have this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EcaBt0Ei6ZvnVSmMlPrA?p=preview) to view quick, the modal is on fixed position with top and left = 0, but it shows inside the tab.

the CSS:

```
.modal{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}
.content-modal{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

the html:

```
<md-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="false">
  <md-tab label="first">
    <div class="modal" *ngIf="modal">
      <div class="content-modal">
        a<br>
        <button md-raised-button (click)="modal=false">close modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="normalContent">
      Content tab goes here...<br>
      <button md-raised-button (click)="modal=true">open modal</button>

    </div>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="second"><div class="modal">b</div>
  here other content
  </md-tab>  
</md-tab-group>
```

[Plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/EcaBt0Ei6ZvnVSmMlPrA?p=preview)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted your markup a little. You have to put the modal div outside of the md-tab to get the fullscreen wide 'veil' modal.

```
 <md-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="false">
      <md-tab label="first">
        <div class="normalContent">
          Content tab goes here...<br>
          <button md-raised-button (click)="modal=true">open modal</button>
        </div>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="second"><div class="modal">b</div>
           Here is an other content
      </md-tab>  
 </md-tab-group>
 <div class="modal" *ngIf="modal">
     <div class="content-modal">
        <button md-raised-button (click)="modal=false">close modal</button>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you this works well, but in my project circumstances the modal is in a class component inside the md-tab, so I'd like to know if it's possible to do it. My solution for now is what you show and passing the information via an @Output decorator event, but it would be nice to have it inside the component.

Comment: You can put the whole code inside your component view.